# Change the default message name in WCF wsdl

Tags: wcf

I have created a WCF service application using DataContract, the service is generating its own default message names. My Service is being used by a Java client, I have to get rid of these default message names, as it is causing to generate java proxy classes based on these long names.

wsdl:message name="**MyService-v1-1_Login_InputMessage**"

wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Login"

wsdl:message

wsdl:message name="**MyService-v1-1_Login_OutputMessage**"

wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LoginResponse"

wsdl:message

wsdl:message name="**MyService-v1-1_Login_ServiceFault_FaultMessage**"

wsdl:part name="detail" element="tns:ServiceFault"

Comment: are you setting any of the attribute properties like name?

Comment: Yes.. below is my service interface   

[OperationContract(Name = "Login")]
[FaultContract(typeof(ServiceFault), Name = "ServiceFault")]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "LoginRequest")]
UserAuthenticationToken Login([MessageParameter(Name = "LoginResponse")]LoginRequest LoginRequest);

but still has no affect on my generated wsdl

Comment: See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05f97251-8d25-476f-b4d3-4278d3a50604/how-to-change-default-wsdl-message-name-for-fault-exception

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IWsdlExportExtension to control this. See the example on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx

The pertinent code

```
            // Get parameter information.
            ParameterInfo[] args = op.SyncMethod.GetParameters();
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
              object[] docAttrs 
                = args[i].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WsdlParameterDocumentationAttribute), false);
              if (docAttrs.Length != 0)
              {
                // <param name="Int1">Text.</param>
                XmlElement newParamElement = opOwner.CreateElement("param");
                XmlAttribute paramName = opOwner.CreateAttribute("name");
                paramName.Value = args[i].Name;
                newParamElement.InnerText 
                  = ((WsdlParameterDocumentationAttribute)docAttrs[0]).ParamComment;
                newParamElement.Attributes.Append(paramName);
                operation.DocumentationElement.AppendChild(newParamElement);
              }
            }
```

Comment: is there a sample of how to use this class that implements IWsdlExportExtension Interface.

Comment: I have created a class as per the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx and tried to use it as an attribute in my service contract, but has no affect. Is there a different way to specify the attribute

Comment: You are supposed to implement it on the 'endpoint, contract, or operation behavior'. I'm not sure about it on an attribute.